# entity_load causes infinite recursion?

Tags: entities

I have a custom module which is supposed to change a user's profile picture.

When you are logged in as a super-admin, the module works fine. Problems arise, however, when you log in as a regular user.

I believe that `entity_load()` is causing infinite recursion, either crashing PHP (due to an xdebug limitation) or running to the PHP memory limit.

I located something similar [here](https://drupal.org/node/636992), but that's from 2009! Surely it's been integrated into Drupal's core by now, yes? Also, I tried to apply [the last green patch](https://drupal.org/files/issues/entity_prepare_view-636992-36.patch) using Git, but it appears that the directory structure is different than my install? `common.inc` is definitely in my `includes` folder, but there's no `node` folder in my `includes` folder, so I'm not quite sure how to apply it..

The full stack trace can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/FYth7wu7)

If anyone could help me figure out what I need to do to fix this, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Any chance you're calling `user_load()` from inside a `hook_user_load()` or `hook_entity_load()` implementation? Something like that would explain it. The patch you linked to has been in for ages so it's not that

Comment: What does realname_user_load do? Is it a get funtion? It is named as a hook as well. This has caused me trouble in the past, too.

Comment: In case XDebug is masking a potential error report by crashing out, try upping the max nesting in php.ini to something like `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 10000` temporarily.

Comment: I'm definitely not calling `user_load()` from within either of those hooks within my own module, but @larrydahooster has a point in that it looks like maybe the `realname` module is doing it? I've been looking through their code and can't see where they would do that, though...

Comment: Nah [`realname_user_load()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/realname/realname.module/function/realname_user_load/7) behaves itself, it's not to blame. It's just an implementation of `hook_user_load()` that gets called every time `user_load()` does. If there's a bunch of user data on the page it's perfectly normal to see that

Comment: @larrydahooster I moved this to the comments as it wasn't an answer...realname is a module, and og is Organic Groups. At a guess, this is some sort of forum page that shows users next to their posts, hence the (perfectly valid) calls to `user_load()`

Comment: @tigertrussell If you disable your module does the problem go away?

Comment: Could you provide a stacktrace with param values? At least for a few loops?

Comment: @Clive Actually, this is a `form_submit()` and the only reason I call `user_load()` at all is to alter the user's picture and `user_save()` it. Also, the problem only occurs when I submit to this form (as far as I know), so disabling my module isn't an option. I can try to do some other stuff on this user account to see if that triggers the issue as well. Currently increasing xdebug's nesting limit to see if there are any errors like you said.

Comment: @Clive If I set xdebug's nesting limit that high, I just get "this webpage is not available" from Chrome. Dunno if that's a 408 or what...

Comment: @Clive if I turn off the Real Name module, all is good. No error...

Comment: I don't know much about the Real Name module (it was installed by my predecessor), but it appears that this particular user's account is screwed up. For instance, the user does not appear to have a name (no name appears where it should on the site), but then when the user's "Profile" is edited (a consequence of the "Edit Profile" module?), their name is populated in those fields... very strange. I logged in as another user (whose name does appear in the correct place) and everything works fine for them :\